# Is 0 False and all other integer values True?

Tags: python, boolean-logic

I've been looking at a really tricky piece of python code. I know the answer but I don't understand why the answer is what it is.

```
def f(x): 
    return x

def g(x, y):
    if x(y):         # does x(3) == True?
        return not y # is != 3 == False?
    return y

x = 3
x = g(f, x)
f = g(f, 0)
```

So from what I'm being told, the value of the variable x when `g(x,y)` is first called resolves to False. I'm confused as to why this is because of the below line:

```
if x(y)
```

This calls `f(x)` from inside `g(x,y)` and passes 3 to it. Then the `f(x)` returns 3 again, which somehow triggers `return not y`. Is `x(3)` equivalent to `True` in this case?? Why is that? Then, the next time `f(x)` is called and passed 0, `return y` is triggered. Does this mean `x(0)` is `False`? Also what is the value of `not y` because I'm being told it's `False` and I don't understand how the value of `not 3` is somehow `False`. I'm really sorry if the way I'm asking this is confusing but I'm unsure how else to go about it. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: yes 0 boolean value is False and all other +ve integers boolean value is True.

Comment: There are a number of things that you can evaluate in a boolean context that aren't actually boolean values.  E.g. lists (an empty list is `False`, everything else is `True`), dictionaries (ditto), sets (ditto)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 and 1 are analogous to booleans `False` and `True` respectively.

You can test it like:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
```

In fact every number that is not zero, is truthy:

```
>>> bool(3)
True
```

which again confirms that a `not` on number (non-zero) yields `False` (not `True` = `False`):

```
>>> not True
False
>>> not 3
False
```

Comment: I see. Therefore, not 3 would be False because it's essentially equivalent to not True, which is False, correct?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, added that as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `if` statement like `if x`, Python actually checks the value of `bool(x)`. `bool` is implemented by the "dunder method" `__bool__`, which is implemented on integers with exactly the behavior you observed:

```
In [1]: bool(1)    
Out[1]: True       

In [2]: bool(2)    
Out[2]: True       

In [3]: bool(0)    
Out[3]: False
```

Of course, as you might expect:

```
In [4]: bool(True)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: bool(False)
Out[5]: False
```

This rule is fairly general. `None`, `0`, `[]`, `{}`, empty containers in general, etc., are all "falsey", while anything else is "truthy".

```
In [6]: bool(None)
Out[6]: False

In [7]: bool([])
Out[7]: False
```

but

```
In [9]: bool([0])
Out[9]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

These examples may help. Basically when you pass g(f, 0), it returns false, so it returns y, not (not y). Any other number is true, so it passes not y, which is false for any number. I hope that helps.

```
In [7658]: not True                                                                                                                                                               
Out[7658]: False

In [7659]: not False                                                                                                                                                              
Out[7659]: True

In [7660]: not 0                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[7660]: True

In [7661]: not 1                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[7661]: False

In [7662]: not 3                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[7662]: False

In [7673]: g(f, 0)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[7673]: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

An int of 0, a float of 0.0, an empty list/tuple/dict/set, an empty string or byte, a None are all Falsy in Python, meaning they are evaluated as False. Anything else is Truthy. In case of integers, any non-zero integer is Truthy.

So in the below code:

```
if x:
    print('yay')
else:
    print('nay')
```

If `x` is one of the Falsy values summarized above, always 'nay' will be printed. For any non-Falsy `x`, always 'yay' will be printed.